# click will remove some class somewhere on the page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have a onepage site with some navigation, when I click on a navlink it needs to be active, (some div gets visible). In the popup div there is a close link and when clicked the close link the navigation buttons needs to be unactive.

So basicly get a link active and get it unactive after clicking on a other link.

I made a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/TKnUZ/1/

```
$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

When click on unlink, the links needs to be unactive!

Comment: Consider using `$('a.link.active').removeClass('active');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add a new click handler to remove the 'active' class on every link (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKnUZ/4/))

```
$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });

   $('a.close').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('active'); 
   });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it wasn't that hard :D

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same thing in a click event for the .close class on the hyperlink

```
$(function() {    
    $('a.close').click(function(){
       $('a.link').removeClass('active'); 
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the function only accommodates for a.link and the close link is a.close and so is not getting picked up in that function. This will work:
http://jsfiddle.net/TKnUZ/6/

```
$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
    $('a.close').click(function(){
         $('a.link').removeClass('active');                   
    })
 });​
```

however im not sure if you were trying to handle it all in the first one click method... Hope it helps at least